# How can I define a method aside a class inside a module?

Tags: ruby, class, methods, module

How can I define a method aside a class where I use this method inside the same module?

What I want to do:

```
module X
  def bar
    puts 'Hello'
  end

  class Y
    def foo
      bar
    end
  end
end
```

I want to call `bar` method using `Y.new.foo` for example. I want to define methods in my module so that all the classes in this module will inherit them.

Why isn't this working? And what is the closest way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to do? How is it not working? What error do you get?

Comment: Please use English punctuation when writing in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want to include the module in the class, you can't reference the method, as there is no instance to call it on. You can instead:

```
module X
  def self.bar
    puts 'Hello'
  end

  class Y
    def foo
      X.bar
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use a separate object to define shared methods rather than polluting the name space object.

```
module X

  module InstanceMethods
    def bar
      puts 'Hello'
    end
  end

  class Y
    include InstanceMethods
    def foo
      bar
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Why in this particular case the order of the class declaration is important? I mean class Y must be declared after module InstanceMethods.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use many methods, it's better to use include

```
module X
  def bar
    puts 'Hello'
  end

  class Y
    include X
    def foo
      bar
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Works with X.bar in foo.